# Unable to connect to jboss domain-controller WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://192.168.50.106:9990. The connection timed out

Tags: jboss

Enviroment information:
JBOSS EAP7.3 on RHEL 8.8 (RPM installation)

I setted up the service and load successfully but keet showing Connection Timed out when I try to connect from a slave controller or using the `../bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=192.168.50.106:9990`
[image]

Firewalld is stopped and disabled
SELinux in Permissive

Service is listenning on 9990 and Management Console is available...

I don't find anything that show me the reason why I can't connect, attached my configs file in case that some could help...
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jalp9pmunahc7lgqbwqfj/conf.zip?rlkey=zc45dev1srs9staxpeopuauja&dl=0